# Escaping simple-quotation-marks in this Ruby string

Tags: ruby

Maybe I have been coding for too many hours, but I can't realize why I am having a hard time escaping simple-quotation-marks in this Ruby string:

```rb
s = "echo '%name%' > /etc/hostname"
puts s
# => "echo '%name%' > /etc/hostname"
    
s.gsub!(/'/, "\\'")
puts s
# => "echo %name%' > /etc/hostname%name% > /etc/hostname > /etc/hostname"
    
exit(0)
```

When doing `s.gsub!(/'/, "\\'")` I am expecting to get `"echo \'%name%\' > /etc/hostname"`, but instead I am getting `"echo %name%' > /etc/hostname%name% > /etc/hostname > /etc/hostname"`

Comment: From [substitution methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/String.html#class-String-label-Substitution+Methods): _"`\'` corresponds to `$'`, which contains string after match"_. You need to escape it once more: `"\\\\'"`

Comment: Consider using [Shellwords](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/shellwords/rdoc/Shellwords.html) for quoting strings into a shell command: `"echo #{Shellwords.escape("%name%")} > /etc/hostname"`